# Wi-Fi connection fail after configuring wlan

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dns

I have been trying to configure my wifi connection so that the DNS values are correct according to what my ISP had provided. To do this I used the network configuration GUI from Ubuntu 14.04 panel and the connection works perfectly:

[image]

It might also be of importance to publish the `ifconfig`'s output when the wi-fi connection was alive and working:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:1a:04:a4:f0:31  
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::721a:4ff:fea4:f031/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5685 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1534231 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:1228569 (1.2 MB)
```

My problem occurred when out of curiosity, I tried to set the values provided by the ISP by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`. I deleted the numbers from the dialog box shown above and put the below information in the `interfaces` file:

```
auto wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.120
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 185.98.113.113 185.98.114.114
```

Unfortunately after running `sudo service network-manager restart` in the terminal, I saw that the wi-fi connection has dropped and there is no networks available anymore.
Would you please help me understand what has been incorrect in either the process I've taken or the data I have entered into the `interfaces` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your interfaces file needs a gateway address; not broadcast. Second, every wireless interface needs to be directed to connect to a specific SSID and provide a password. I suggest that you amend your file to:

```
auto wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.120
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 185.98.113.113 185.98.114.114
  wpa-ssid <your_network>
  wpa-psk <your_secret_key>
```

Finally, Network Manager needs to be directed to *NOT* manage any interfaces declared in /etc/network/interfaces. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Make certain that *managed=false*. If it is, simply close the text editor. If not, change it, proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and check:

```
ifconfig
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But now the problem is that although I am connected to the Internet, I have neither no access to other wi-fi networks  nor I can disconnect from this network easily whenever I want. Many of the options in the panel are now disabled !!

Comment: That's the choice you make; either the *interfaces* file or Network Manager. If yours is a stay-at-home computer, then *interfaces* is perfectly acceptable.  If you need to go to work or the university or the coffee shop, then I recommend you clear out the wlan settings from *interfaces* and let NM do the work.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I just did. Thank you very much for your help. I am very new to the networking idea in Linux and it was awesome to be guided by you.

Comment: I was very happy to help. I'm glad it's all working.